# Yet another 'Unknown provider' for an AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I actually hate to be that guy, but I've been sitting with this
problem for some days now. I have these three files as a part of a
larger angularjs application. I can not get even this rudimentary test
to pass (or even work). I've been comparing files within the project,
I've read on-line (tried all those ways people have suggested). I have
even written the files from scratch a few times. I'm probably not able
to see my error anymore. I guess this is easier to spot (right away)
for a back-seat driver.

I'd be most appreciative for any help.

The output from gulp/karma

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) SiteDescriptionService the service should be defined FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SiteDescriptionServiceProvider <- SiteDescriptionService
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=SiteDescriptionServiceProvider%20%3C-%20SiteDescriptionService (line 4511)
    bower_components/angular/angular.js:4511:86
    getService@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4664:46
    bower_components/angular/angular.js:4516:48
    getService@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4664:46
    injectionArgs@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4688:68
    invoke@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4710:31
    workFn@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3085:26
    loaded@http://localhost:8080/context.js:151:17
    inject@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3051:28
    app/service/sitedescriptor-service-test.js:10:19
    app/service/sitedescriptor-service-test.js:4:13
    global code@app/service/sitedescriptor-service-test.js:1:9
    Expected undefined to be truthy.
    app/service/sitedescriptor-service-test.js:17:32
    loaded@http://localhost:8080/context.js:151:17
```

The module declaration

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('application.service', []);

})();
```

The service itself

```
(function () {
  angular.module('application.service')
    .service('SiteDescriptorService',
         ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
         var lastRequestFailed = true,
             promise,
             items = [];

         return {
             name: 'SiteDescriptorService',

             getItems: function () {
             if (!promise || lastRequestFailed) {
                 promise = $http.get('site.json').then(
                 function (response) {
                     lastRequestFailed = false;
                     items = response.data;
                     return items;
                 }, function (response) {  // error
                     lastRequestFailed = true;
                     return $q.reject(response);
                 });
             }
             return promise;
             }
         };
         }]
        );

})();
```

and the test

```
describe('SiteDescriptionService', function() {
'use strict';

describe('the service', function() {

    var service, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('application.service'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_SiteDescriptionService_, $httpBackend) {
    service = _SiteDescriptionService_;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    console.log(service);
    }));

    it('should be defined', function() {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
});
```

Cheers
Mats

Comment: check the service name

Comment: just an afterthought, have you tried typescript

Comment: I've seen it around and I surely like the thought of a 'more strict' JavaScript, but my history with Microsoft technology makes me hesitant to pick it up. You like it, I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just use incorrect name when injecting dependency, should be 'SiteDescriptorService' and not 'SiteDescriptionService'

Comment: What can I say? F*** me! I told you I've read it too many times and got blind. Thanks a lot. Cheers

Comment: I want to cry now

Comment: it happens to me all the time, do not feel bad.